# Can't understand why the final result of this integration is positive

Tags: thermodynamics, integration, information

So, this excerpt is from this paper: [Thermodynamics as a theory of decision-making with information-processing costs](https://royalsocietypublishing.org/doi/full/10.1098/rspa.2012.0683), the final equation doesn't follow the math, since the final result is positive, can someone explain what's going on here, or if it is an error?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No idea what the physics is.

However does this answer your question?

$$-kT\ln(\frac{V'}{V}) = kT\ln(\frac{V}{V'}) = kT \ln(c)$$

Edit: I think with their definition of c, it should be

$$kT \ln(\frac{1}{c})$$

Comment: This solution seems likely if haven't substituted V' = cV and they haven't even mentioned that those two c's are different.

Comment: I agree, their solution is incorrect, I think.

Comment: After reading the paper again, I think that this equation is converting energy into information, and since information can't be negative, the final result is positive.
-https://www.scientificamerican.com/article/energy-and-information/

The author has cited this paper while explaining about kT.

Comment: That's indeed a typo. In the thesis (https://www.adaptiveagents.org/_media/papers/thesis.pdf, Eq 6.2, page 82) you'll find the correct derivation and motivation.